# C++ class loop in main

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, loops, class

I need help in a simple way of solving a part of my code that i cant seem to make it work.The point of my "assignment" is that everything must try to be in one class.Now the problem i am having is at a part of my code where it is suppose to "print" the n number of products meaning that it displays what you  have  inputted in the void get() part,but the problem i cant seem to resolve is it only prints the last name,amount,weight of the product and not everything written.

```
   class Class
{
public:
    string name;
    int n, amount;
    float weight;
    void market()
    {
        cout << "Give the number of products you want to get at Market : " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }
    void get()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << "Give product name,amount and weight : " << endl;
            cin >> name >> amount >> weight;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "\nProduct display:\n" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << name << " - " << amount << " , " << weight << " kg" << endl;
            cout << "------------------------" << endl;
        }
    };
};
```

The main part.

```
int main()
    {
            Class market;
            market.market();
            market.get();
            market.print();

    }
```

Comment: **Tip:** Avoid declaring class variables as public, they breaks the rule of OOP.

Comment: But you have not stored *all* the `names`, `weight`s, etc. You should use a `vector` to store *all* of the information you need. Also, your class should not be named `Class`, that's not a descriptive name. How about `Market` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a `std::vector<TYPE>` (example 1), or array for holding multiple data in a single variable (example 2).

### Example 1

Since you've been coding in C++ programming language, it's highly recommended to use `std::vector<>` for best results.

Consider the class example (read comments too):

```
int count = 0; // PRIVATE SECTION
char ask;
std::vector<std::string> name;
std::vector<int> amount;
std::vector<float> weight;
std::string tName; // temp variables
int tAmount;
float tWeight;

public:

void market()
{
    cout << "WELCOME!" << endl; // nothing's required with vector
}
void get()
{
    do {
        cout << "Give product name, amount and weight : " << endl;
        cin >> tName >> tAmount >> tWeight; // getting temporary variables

        name.push_back(tName); // assigning
        amount.push_back(tAmount);
        weight.push_back(tWeight);

        count++;

        cout << "Add more? (Y/n): "; // add more? Go on if yes...
        cin >> ask;

    } while (ask == 'Y' || ask == 'y');
}
void print()
{
    cout << "\nProduct display:\n"
         << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << name[i] << " - " << amount[i] << " , " << weight[i] << " kg" << endl;
        cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    }
}
```

> **Sample Output**

```
WELCOME!
Give product name, amount and weight :
ABC 12 55.5
Add more? (Y/n): y
Give product name, amount and weight :
SSD 33 43.2
Add more? (Y/n): n

Product display:

ABC - 12 , 55.5 kg
------------------------
SSD - 33 , 43.2 kg
------------------------
```

### Example 2

You can do the same thing just with few modifications, but having static number isn't considered dynamic. You can use arrays for your program as stated below.

Rather than:

```
string name;
int n, amount;
float weight;
```

Consider `const int MAX = 1024;` and use (class variables must be visible only inner the class and nowhere else):

```
private: // declare on top of the class ("private:" is by default and redundant)
    string name[MAX];
    int n, amount[MAX];
    float weight[MAX];
```

Edited & working example class:

```
void get()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Give product name,amount and weight : " << endl;
        cin >> name[i] >> amount[i] >> weight[i];
    }
}
void print()
{
    cout << "\nProduct display:\n"
         << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << name[i] << " - " << amount[i] << " , " << weight[i] << " kg" << endl;
        cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    }
}
```

> **Sample Output**

```
Give the number of products you want to get at Market :
2
Give product name,amount and weight :
ABC 25 102
Give product name,amount and weight :
BDE 22 333

Product display:

ABC - 25 , 102 kg
------------------------
BDE - 22 , 333 kg
------------------------
```

Comment: Since this is c++, I would strongly recommend showing the `vector` version of the code, instead of the static array one.

Comment: Thanks. Also, make it the *first* example, and the array version the second. Many people will just use the first example they see that works.

Comment: Ok, not sure why that's a problem though. Besides, `market` could allocate/reserve the needed size, and then the code in `get` would be identical.

Comment: @cigien added vector example, inform me if it's enough information.

Comment: Looks good. The OP does want to accept the number of inputs separately, but there's enough information in the answer for them to figure that out, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually overwriting `name`, `amount` and `weight`. You have to make use of something similar to `std::vector`:

```cpp
class Class {
    public:
        std::vector<string> names;
        // Same for others
```

When you get them from `std::cin` you have to push them into the vector:

```cpp
names.push_back(name);
amounts.push_back(amount);
weights.push_back(weight);
```

When printing you loop over the vectors:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << names[i] << " - " << amounts[i] << " , " << weights[i] << " kg" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason for the data to be public, so why not suggest that it be private instead?

Comment: There's no reason for it to be private either. We don't know what is the final goal of the code. I just respected his decision to be public

Comment: From the provided code, there's no reason for it to be public. Members should always be private, *unless* there is some very specific reason not to be.